# Probability Convergency / Stochastically bounded

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

We have a random variable $Y_n$ stochastically bounded, so for each $\epsilon \geq 0$ ,   $\exists$ a constant  K and a value $n_0 = n_0 (\epsilon)$ such that  $P(\left | Y_n \right |\leq K) \geq 1- \epsilon$ . So we now consider another random variable $X_n$, and we know:

$$ \frac{X_n}{Y_n} \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0 \textrm{when n} {\rightarrow} \infty $$

And we want to prove:

$$ X_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0 \textrm{when n} {\rightarrow} \infty $$

So this is what i think:

Applying probability convergency definition

$$ lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  P( \left | \frac{X_n}{Y_n} \right | > \epsilon ) =0  \Rightarrow $$

$$ lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  P( |X_n| > \epsilon . |Y_n| ) =0 $$

And here because $Y_n$ is stochastically bounded we can take $\epsilon$ as little as we want so the new $\epsilon$ would be $\epsilon . |Y_n|$. In this way $X_n$ converge in probability to $0$. But i do not know if this is right, and if it is actually right how can i put it in math expressions including the use of $n_0$

Comment: Hi Gabriel , thank you so much! I think it does answer my question but i do not understand the first part when $\left | Y_n \right | > \epsilon $ implies $\left | \frac{Y_n}{X_n} \right | > \frac{\epsilon}{M}$ or $\left | X_n \right | \geq M$